# Dynamic wizard with varying number of questions

Tags: design-patterns, wizard

I have a page that guides the user to the required information.
It asks a question and based on the answer displays a second question. Based on that answer - the information is displayed.
There can be between 2 to 4 questions.

Tried to look for nice solutions, but perhaps I am missing the correct terminology for such a thing.

Is there a term for this so that I can find design patterns?
Do you have good examples or design patterns for such a page?

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply call that a branching logic  form or a conditional form. It is also the underlying principle behind a "wizard" style interface: the user is given one choice or option at a time, and based on the results of that choice/option they are given the next. This can be done in sections of a form that are progressively disclosed, or one panel at a time. Ideally you plan this out by creating a workflow that shows all of the options and which option takes people where.

For classic examples of how this works, play around with a free Google Forms or Surveymonkey survey and add conditional logic to some of your questions.

Or pick up a Choose Your Own Adventure book! ;-)

Ok - found one example. This registration form all takes place on one screen. The users first tell us what country their organization is in:

[image]

Depending on the country chosen, the fields are different. For example, if they choose USA, they see these:

[image]

And if they choose a different country, the options are different (apologies for the placeholder content, this was a work-in-progress):

[image]

A simple example, but you gret the idea. The down side is that it requires more coding and a heavier page to include all of the options on a single page. But you could put whatever information and/or questions you want on each of those states, and continue that down the page until you get to your final presentation of information.

Comment: Ok. But I am looking for a single form and that not all questions are displayed at once. For example, Question2 is only displayed if you choose Answer1 in Question1. Otherwise, Question3 is displayed.

Neither google forms or survey monkey support that.

Any good example for something like that?

Comment: Ok, found a very meager example and I added it to my answer above. But in none of the examples cited before would you show all of the options at once... each state would be progressively disclosed based on the answers from the previous section.